# How to place a table next to google chart

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using Bootstrap v3 and in one case I am opening a modal. The modal has a single tab, the tab item corresponds to a div. In that div i want to place a google chart and next to it a data table. I am unable to get the chart and it's data table next to each other.

Following is the code i used:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
                        <div id="chart_div">
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Risk</b></td>
                                <td><b>Total Individuals</b></td>
                                <td><b>%</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How could i get the chart and the table be exactly next to each other.

Comment: `#home>* { display:inline-block; width:50%; box-sizing:border-box }`

Comment: thats is still stacking it, table below the chart.

Answer (score 0):

`#chart_div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}`

Comment: this does not work either. Should the table be in its own div?